# Can't see my button text inside JTable model cell

Tags: java, jtable, jbutton

Didn't exactly know what was wrong with my button text part but it doesn't show the button text delete.

I am displaying a table from a text file that has a button at the last column that is a button for delete and I followed this tutorial

http://camposha.info/source/java-jtable-button-column/

What he did was use the existing columns that already had data so I tried changing the data to Delete instead but the table doesn't display the text although it does display a clickable button.

**Code to read text from file to place into table:**

```
class myStoreHouse extends JPanel {
    private JPanel buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
    private JButton homeButton = new JButton("Back");
     FileReader file;
     String wholeLine;
     private JTable table;
     private DefaultTableModel model;
     JScrollPane scroll;
     String[][] data = new String[50][50];
     String[] column = {"Item Name", "Category", "Date of Expiry", ""};
     int noOfRows = 0;

    public myStoreHouse(){
        try {
            file = new FileReader("expiryDateEntry.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
            System.out.println("hi");
            wholeLine ="";
            while((wholeLine = br.readLine())!= null){
                int count = 0;
                String delQuotes = "";
                System.out.println(wholeLine);
                String regex = "([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*";
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(wholeLine);
                    while(m.find()){
                        if(m.group(1) != null){
                            delQuotes = m.group(1).replace("\"", "");
                            if(count == 0){
                                data[noOfRows][count ] = delQuotes;
                                System.out.println(delQuotes);
                            }
                            if(count == 1){
                                data[noOfRows][count ] = delQuotes;
                            }
                            if(count == 2){
                                data[noOfRows][count ] = delQuotes;
                            }
                            if(count == 3){
                                data[noOfRows][count] = "Delete";
                            }
                        }
                        if(count < column.length) count++;
                    }

                noOfRows++; 
            }
            model = new DefaultTableModel(data,column);
            table = new JTable(model);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JTextField()));
            scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(getButton(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
```

**ButtonRenderer**

```
  class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements  TableCellRenderer
     {

       //CONSTRUCTOR
       public ButtonRenderer() {
         setOpaque(true);
       }
       @Override
       public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj,
           boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int col) {

         //SET PASSED OBJECT AS BUTTON TEXT
         setText((obj==null) ? "":obj.toString());
         return this;
       }

     }
```

**ButtonEditor**

```
     class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
     {
       protected JButton btn;
        private String lbl;
        private Boolean clicked;

        public ButtonEditor(JTextField txt) {
         super(txt);

         btn=new JButton("");
         btn.setOpaque(true);

         //WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED
         btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             fireEditingStopped();
           }
         });
       }


        @Override
       public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object obj,
           boolean selected, int row, int col) {

           //SET TEXT TO BUTTON,SET CLICKED TO TRUE,THEN RETURN THE BTN OBJECT
          lbl=(obj==null) ? "":obj.toString();
          btn.setText(lbl);
          clicked=true;
          return btn;
       }

       //IF BUTTON CELL VALUE CHNAGES,IF CLICKED THAT IS
        @Override
       public Object getCellEditorValue() {

            if(clicked ==  true)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn, "Are you sure?");
            }
            clicked=false;
            return new String(lbl);
       }

        @Override
       public boolean stopCellEditing() {
            clicked=false;
            return super.stopCellEditing();
       }

        @Override
       protected void fireEditingStopped() {
            super.fireEditingStopped();
       }
     }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that your `data` array is getting filled by values? In case your matcher does not find 4 matches in `wholeLine` then "Delete" will never get added to `data`. Try adding `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));` before you create the `DefaultTableModel` object to see what data are actually added to the array.

Comment: @MatheM Yes, my table has value added from the text file in the other three columns. The only problem is my Delete not showing in the last column. Oh I see what you mean, let me try. Yes, it works! Thanks a lot, I must have forgot that the matcher only finds 3 matches. If you could answer, I can close this question already.

Comment: I don't really know how to formulate my comment into an answer. Technically there was nothing wrong with your code, if you want you can answer your own question and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the condition due to the code not reaching count = 3 as there are only 3 matches for m.find() and as such it will never touch the `if(count == 3)`. All I needed to do was add another line `data[noOfRows][count+1] = "Delete";` in the condition when count == 2 .

```
while(m.find()){
    if(m.group(1) != null){
        delQuotes = m.group(1).replace("\"", "");
    if(count == 0){
        data[noOfRows][count ] = delQuotes;
        System.out.println(delQuotes);
    }
    if(count == 1){
        data[noOfRows][count ] = delQuotes;
    }
    if(count == 2){
        data[noOfRows][count] = delQuotes;
        data[noOfRows][count+1] = "Delete";
    }
    }
    if(count < column.length) count++;
}
```